# If $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Morse function then $f$ has an even number of critical points.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, morse-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Let $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth Morse function, then $f$ has an even number of critical point.

---

**My progress:**

I was able to prove that if $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a Morse function with finite critical points $t_1 < ...< t_n$ then the index of the critical points must alternate (the details of this affirmation can be seen in the answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840938/can-a-proper-morse-function-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-have-infinitely-many-criti)), *i.e;*
$$\text{sgn} (g'' (t_i)) =(-1)^{n-1} \text{sgn} (g'' (t_1)). $$

If $ x_1,..., x_k$ are the critical points of $f$, then we can define the diffeomorphism

$$\varphi: S^1\setminus\{x_1\} \to \mathbb{R},  $$

where $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism that "looks like" the stereographic projection.

Then $g := f\circ\varphi^{-1} : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, is a Morse function. If we suppose by *reductio ad absurdum*, that $g$ has an even number of critical points $s_1<...<s_{2k}$, then we would conclude that

$$ \text{sgn}(g'(-\infty,s_1)) = (-1)^{2k}\text{sgn}(g'(s_{2k},\infty)) = \text{sgn}(g'(s_{2k},\infty))  $$

I think that this implies that $x_1$ is a degenerated point of $f$, but I wasn't able to show this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As you say, maxima and minima alternate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ S^1 =\{ e^{it}|0\leq t <2\pi\}$, then assume that $f'(0)=0$. So
$$ 0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\cdots < t_n=2\pi $$

where $f'(t_n)=0$. If $f$ is increasing on $[0,t_1]$, then $f$ is
decreasing on $[t_1,t_2]$. That is, $f$ is decreasing on
$[t_{n-1},t_n]$ so that increasing and decreasing intervals have
same number.